# Counting the occurrence of a record in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to display records that have **more than one** occurence, basing them off of a column.

For Example:

```
 id          user_id
------      --------
  1          FA068
  2          FA068
  3          FA068
  4          FA145
  5          FA111
  6          FA200
  7          FA200
  8          FA155
  9          FA145
  10         FA145
```

And I want this to be the output:

```
 id          user_id
------      --------
  1          FA068
  2          FA068
  3          FA068
  6          FA200
  7          FA200
  9          FA145
  10         FA145
```

I want to display all the records of those that have more than one occurrence basing from the `user_id` column.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: what did you try and did not work?

Comment: Thanks for this! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
select * from my_table where user_id in
(select user_id from my_table group by user_id having count(user_id) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily count records and use HAVING clause

```
SELECT `user_id`, COUNT(*)  AS num
FROM `table`
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING num > 1
```